# render a php application inside Joomla article

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a folder containing a php booking system,that i want to render as un article and add it to the main menu of the site.
The solution that i end with, is to use the joomla URL Wrapper. But it brokes my design as it render it inside an iframe.

Is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That requires an integration work. At least you'd rather think of the way to give some Jooml Component wrapper to your booking sysytem. which at least involves creating a com_yourcomname folder, and a yourcomname.php that will dispatch your actions to the actions of the booking component and, perhaps, filter the urls in the output so that they match the Joomla url building convetions. If do this properly, your app will appear as a page content (not an article)

Comment: The application has its own database. I just want to display it as Joomla menu page. Do I need to create a component for that?

Comment: I believe, you have to (unless resorting to iframe solution). Faced the same problem several times (however on earlier versions of Joomla, 1.3 and 1.5) and that's what I found to be the most efficient solution

Answer (score 1):

Use *Jumi*, it **includes** PHP files into articles, without iframes.

Usage:

```
{jumi [path/to/file.php]}
```

[Jumi website](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/1023)

Comment: How to integrate a whole php application, including subfolders, using Jumi?

Comment: If you have to integrate a whole application i suggest you to make a content plugin or (better) a module which you then will include in your joomla